# Separate front-end and back-end views in Laravel

Tags: laravel, view

This is how I want my resources folder structure should look like

```
resource
--------- admin
-------------- views
-------------- layouts
--------- front
-------------- views
-------------- layouts
```

How can I achieve this in Laravel?

Comment: That would require custom logic to specify where the `view()` helper (and others) points to. Could you do `resources > views > admin` and `resources > views > front` as an alternative?

Comment: no, I don't want an alternative, I know about, Can you tell me how can I achieve my desired results with custom logic? Thanks

Comment: No, sorry I can't, as I don't know what the custom logic would be. If I knew, I would have left an answer for you. Regardless, good luck! And try to solve this issue yourself first; please remember that Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I didn't mention you, bro. I'm saying to person who did this act. Instead, I'm thankful to you for your kind comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 layout.blade.php file one for admin side and one for frontend side.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is wrong you can set multiple custom view directories but the problem lies when you have same-named blade file in multiple directories.

`config/view.php`

```
'paths' => [
        resource_path('admin'),
        resource_path('front'),
    ],
```

Directory Structure

```
resources
--admin
----layouts
----admin.blade.php
--front
----layouts
----front.blade.php
```

Access in controller e.g.

```
view('admin'); // This will return admin/admin.blade.php view
```

Note: these directories should not have same-named files.

The correct way is don't set multiple view directories to make directory structure like this

```
resources
--views
----admin
------layouts
------index.blade.php
----front
------layouts
------index.blade.php
```

Comment: doing same as you told for app/view.php change, when trying to use this route: http://localhost/mobileshop/public/ getting error : View [welcome] not found.
While welcome fils is there in front/view/welcome.blade.php
and in web. php code is :
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Comment: @AliBhutta Adding on to this answer, you will need to edit the provided config values to use your "views" folders to access the welcome view like that. ie: `resource_path('admin/views')` and `resource_path('front/views')`

Comment: @Sawyer if you do `front/views` then you can not get layouts folder

Comment: @MayurSojitra You're correct, then in the example provided, maybe put the `index.blade.php` file in a "views" folder like the structure he described so he can then clearly see how to use his `views.welcome` as that's the issue he used in his comment.